# access self.view.bounds in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, interface-orientation

In my app I want to keep an image centered after a device rotation. For this I'm using the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation methods to determine a translation-vector. I'm using the following code:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
  NSLog(@"%s ...", __func__);
  NSLog(@"\t self.view=%@", self.view);
  NSLog(@"\t self.view.bounds=%@", self.view.bounds);
  NSLog(@"\t self.view.frame=%@", self.view.frame);
  NSLog(@"\t self.view.frame=%@", [[self view] frame]);
  // Save previous bounds to determine translation after rotation occurred.
  _previousViewBounds = self.view.bounds;
}
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
  NSLog(@"%s ...", __func__);
  NSLog(@"\t self.view=%@", self.view);
  NSLog(@"\t self.view.bounds=%@", self.view.bounds);
  NSLog(@"\t self.view.frame=%@", self.view.frame);
  NSLog(@"\t self.view.frame=%@", [[self view] frame]);
  // Restore previous view.bounds and use new view.bounds to calculate translation.
  CGFloat tx = self.view.bounds.origin.x - _previousViewBounds.origin.x;
  CGFloat ty = self.view.bounds.origin.y - _previousViewBounds.origin.y;
  // ... do translation stuff ...
}
```

I really don't understand why I can't access the self.view.bounds or self.view.frame members
because my NSLog show the self.view exists. The following output is generated:

```
-[MapViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] ...
  self.view=<UIView: 0x685fcc0; frame = (0 0; 320 367); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x685fcf0>>
  self.view.bounds=(null)
  self.view.frame=(null)
  self.view.frame=(null)

-[MapViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:] ...
  self.view=<UIView: 0x685fcc0; frame = (0 0; 480 219); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x685fcf0>>
  self.view.bounds=(null)
  self.view.frame=(null)
  self.view.frame=(null)
```

Anybody ideas in what's going wrong or I'm missing, because this is really driving me nuts.
Any advice, comments or help very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not center the view in `init` and just set its autoresizing mask to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`?

Comment: Thanks for this tip! It really solved my rotation/view-center issue, however when I hide/show (using code) the Status-, Navigation- and TabBar in my ViewController, changing the available (image)view-size causes unused white space on the top/bottom of my view.
I've the following view-object hierachy: ViewController.view>UIScrollView>UIImageView, where my UIImage contains a very large image which can be scrolled/zoomed. When I want to go full-screen (i.e. hiding the Status/Nav/TabBars) I recalculated the ScrollView-bounds in order to stay centered. This doesn't work after device rotation.

Answer (score 1):

`CGRect` is not an object so you can't log values like this. Try to log NSValue object:

```
NSLog(@"\t self.view.bounds=%@", [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.view.bounds]);
```

Comment: Your right, stupid mistake and I also figured out that using NSLog(@"bounds=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds)); accomplishes the same!

Comment: @H2CO3 you are absolutely right. But I hope these NSLog functions are for studying purposes only an will be removed soon...